# Android Camera FC (unknown method)

Tags: android, camera, forceclose, methodnotfound

I'm using a Samsung Fascinate, the build is a 4.2.1 AOSP (CM10.1 Nightly).

The camera is utterly horrible, so I replaced it.  New Camera FC's on start-up, I pulled a log-cat and got as a stack-trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1814): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-175 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1814): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: **android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.setCameraMode** E/AndroidRuntime( 1814):     at com.android.camera.Camera.updateCameraParametersPreference(Camera.java:2249) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1814): at com.android.camera.Camera.setCameraParameters(Camera.java:2339) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1814):    at com.android.camera.Camera.startPreview(Camera.java:2083) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1814):    at com.android.camera.Camera.access$3700(Camera.java:86) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1814):    at com.android.camera.Camera$5.run(Camera.java:1255) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1814):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I'm okay with this, one thing, though:  It's not kidding there's no such method...I can't find any documentation on that stupid method (**setCameraMode()**) ANYWHERE.  What the heck is it?

Answer (score 1):

The method was available on earlier versions of JB (I think android-4.1.1_r1 AOSP).
Take a look at:
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/jellybean/core/java/android/hardware/Camera.java

So, get used with the stock Camera or install others from the Play Store.